# Android Imageview and Matrix

Tags: android, matrix, imageview

I'm using imageview for displaying Image from image gallery.

not sure but my image is getting little distorted and tilted.

I have tried scale type FITXY but it does not maintain aspect ratio.

Original image is
[image]

what I have currently is 
[image]

I want to have to have similar to

[image]

I'm using below XML

```
 <ImageView
                            android:id="@+id/imageview1"
                            android:layout_width="80dp"
                            android:layout_height="76dp"
                            android:src="@drawable/ic_add_a_photo_black_361px"
                            android:background="@drawable/back"
                            android:scaleType="matrix"
                            android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
                            android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
                            />
```

and below code.

```
Bitmap bMap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(selectedImagePath);
                imageView1.setImageBitmap(bMap);
                Matrix mat = imageView1.getImageMatrix();

                RectF drawableRect = new RectF(0, 0, bMap.getWidth(), bMap.getHeight());
                RectF viewRect = new RectF(0, 0, imageView1.getWidth(), imageView1.getHeight());
                mat.setRectToRect(drawableRect, viewRect, Matrix.ScaleToFit.FILL);
                //mat.postScale(0.1f, 0.1f);
                imageView1.setImageMatrix(mat);
```

any help would be really appreciated.

Comment: why you are using matrix

Comment: I'm not sure...I wanted have a little zoom for images...

Comment: the docs for `FIT_XY`: `FIT_XY Scale the image using FILL` and for `FILL`: `FILL Scale in X and Y independently, so that src matches dst exactly. This may change the aspect ratio of the src.`

Comment: Thanks for info.. I have been dealing with image problems from long time, actually I'm new to android development..I wish you guys can guide me

Answer (score 0):

Try using `android:adjustViewBounds="true"`

**e.g**

```
<ImageView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
    />
```

see [this tutorial](http://inthecheesefactory.com/blog/correct-imageview-adjustviewbounds-with-adjustable-imageview/en)

Comment: with matrix or without?

Comment: without any scaleType